# How to access custom properties on the browser window

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom

I set a Vue app as a property on the browser window. When I `console.log(window)` I see this:

```
window: Window
0: Window {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: "", location: Location, 
......
......
GVue: Cr {_uid: 2, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Cr, _self: Cr, …}
...
```

That GVue is what I am looking to access. It is there when I log window, but when I do `console.log(window.GVue)` it tells me it is `undefined`! I also tried using `Window` instead of `window`

How can I access this window property that I set? Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Could you include the code you're using to set this property?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense in its current form because there's no problem with accessing properties if they exist. Where is `console.log(window.GVue)` used, does it happen in console after `console.log(window)`?

Comment: The code used to set this property on the window is:

`window.GVue = new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#slideout-cart");`

In addition to that, I used a setTimeout with a console.log in the callback out of curiosity and the GVue property was logged correctly, so it appears that for some reason the window hasn't loaded all of its properties or something? I will have to do some more research into how the `window` is initialized